# When extreme yoke movement cuts out stab trim on a 737-NG, does it stay off after yoke returns from limits?

Tags: boeing-737

I've read that the 737-NG has logic built into the stab trim system that will cause stab trim to cut out if the control column (yoke) is pulled/pushed far/hard enough (it's not clear to me if it's travel distance or force thsf causes the cut out).

My question is, given the control column stab trim cutout mentioned above, does it continue to function after the control column is moved back from its hard stops or force is decreased  below a certain value?

Answer (score 1):

From the Boeing 737 NG FCOM v2 (9.20.8 Flight Controls - System Description):

> Control column actuated stabilizer trim cutout switches stop operation of the main
>   electric and autopilot trim when the control column movement opposes trim
>   direction. When the STAB TRIM override switch is positioned to OVERRIDE,
>   electric trim can be used regardless of control column position.

So any opposite movement of the yoke will *stop* the stab trim. There is nothing mentioned in the FCOM about staying off, so I would assume stab trim would continue immediately after the yoke is released.

Answer (score 0):

no, it doesn’t stay off.

further, as we know by now, the yoke has no effect on the MCAS AUTOTRIM on the B 737 max; it is terrific.